# wxpython can't switch panel

Tags: wxpython

Code compiles ok, just having trouble loading up the second panel.
I've looked into many forums on panel switching but none of them seemed to help.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        ##super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        ##                                size=(500,  #width
        ##                                      300)) #height
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(900,270))
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    #define User Interface
    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        #Menu bar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        filem = wx.Menu()
        editm = wx.Menu()
        helpm = wx.Menu()

        menubar.Append(filem, '&File')
        menubar.Append(editm, '&Edit')
        menubar.Append(helpm,'&help')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #buttons
        b1 = wx.Button(self.panel1, label='button', size=(300,30), pos=(0,0))
        hbox.Add(b1)
        b1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB1)


        #panel2
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self.panel1, -1)
        self.panel2.Hide()
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        b2 = wx.Button(self.panel2, label='button2', size=(300,30), pos=(0,0))
        vbox.Add(b2)

    def OnB1(self, event):
        self.panel2.Show()
        self.panel1.Hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Why doesn't this code work right, second panel never shows up with the other button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `panel2` has `panel1` as parent. When you hide parent, you hide its children also.

Also you are not using a main sizer for your frame. That means that one is created for you implicitly and first object added to frame (`panel1`) is put inside this sizer. Your `panel2` is than not included in sizer, so fixing parents would result in `panel2` visible after click, but not resized properly.

You can fix that like this:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        ##super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        ##                                size=(500,  #width
        ##                                      300)) #height
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(900,270))
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    #define User Interface
    def InitUI(self):
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer() # Main window sizer

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        #Menu bar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        filem = wx.Menu()
        editm = wx.Menu()
        helpm = wx.Menu()

        menubar.Append(filem, '&File')
        menubar.Append(editm, '&Edit')
        menubar.Append(helpm,'&help')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #buttons
        b1 = wx.Button(self.panel1, label='button', size=(300,30), pos=(0,0))
        self.hbox.Add(b1)
        b1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnB1)
        self.panel1.SetSizer(self.hbox)


        #panel2
        self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel2, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel2.Hide()
        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        b2 = wx.Button(self.panel2, label='button2', size=(300,30), pos=(0,0))
        self.vbox.Add(b2)
        self.panel2.SetSizer(self.vbox)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer) # Set main window sizer

    def OnB1(self, event):
        self.panel2.Show()
        self.panel1.Hide()
        self.sizer.Layout() # Force the main window sizer to recalculate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    Example(None, title='')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I previously tried that.

User interface doesnt come out right,
On launch, it only shows like a small square at top left corner of second panel, while the rest is blank

Comment: See just added second paragraph.

Comment: How do I set sizer? initially it's done with wx.Frame.__init__(size=(900,270)

Comment: Something like the code just added. Go through some sizer examples, tutorials, demos etc. Mastering sizers is fundamental for wxPython.